# JQuery Document Ready Efficiency

Tags: jquery, performance

Here's a question that I've been asking myself for a while. I have quite a large chunk of JQuery that's held within a single **on ready** function, like so:

```
$(function () {
... do operation 1
... do operation 2
... do operation 3
... do operation 4
... etc
});
```

Provided each operation is self-contained, is it more efficient to have one big function or to have multiple functions, for example:

```
$(function () {
... do operation 1
});
$(function () {
... do operation 2
});
$(function () {
... do operation 3
});
etc
```

Comment: If there is an effect, it'd be completely unnoticeable, unless maybe if you had tens of thousands of operations, in which case a single function would be slightly better

Comment: If you have multiple jQuery libraries, or are splitting your jQuery logic across multiple files, you're already doing the second approach. As @CertainPerformance states, the difference is absolutely miniscule. I'd run a jsPerf on it, but they're down for new tests right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every duplicate of a code will result in a worse performance, in one way or another.

Always try to prevent duplicated in the code.

[Here you can see a benchmark test between the 2 scenarios](http://jsben.ch/wZjoM).

I didn't use jQuery in the benchmark because of limitations of the benchmark software, but you can get the idea.

### Conclusion

There is no reason as much as I can think of, to split the code into multiple `on ready` functions, it will be less efficient because of duplication of code.